# How to re-use C structs in ARM assembly in a maintainable and readable way?

Tags: c, assembly, struct, arm

When accessing struct fields, I've been manually adding offsets to addresses to get access to the fields. This is pretty tedious, hard to read and a maintenance headache.

Is there a nicer way to access C struct fields?

For example, I'm thinking of a syntax like this:

example.h:
`typedef struct { int a; int b; } MyStruct;`

example.s:
`ldr r1, [r2, #MyStruct.b] // r2 contains an address to a MyStruct`

Comment: Well written assembly is, yes.

Comment: @Claris Readability isn't binary. Certainly some assembly code is more readable than other.

Comment: Much better: Write C, use e.g. GCC's inline assembly to embed assembly snippets where relevant. ARM won't last forever...

Answer (score 6):

There is really no clean and portable way.  Most projects I've seen that do have some build step that generates a header file of struct offsets.  It goes a little something like this:

1) Create a C file that defines your offsets

```
#include "mystruct.h"

#define DECLARE(SYM,VAL) \
__asm("__AS_DEFINE__ " SYM "\t%0" : : "n" ((unsigned long)(VAL)))

void foo(void)
{
    // mystruct.h
    DECLARE("MYSTRUCT_B",  offsetof(struct mystruct, b));
}
```

2) Compile that file with the flag to generate assembly (-S on Clang or GCC).  This will create an assembly file with a bunch of defined lines such as:

```
    __AS_DEFINE__ MYSTRUCT_B    #4
```

3) Use some shell tricks to turn these into a header file for your assembly code.

```
grep '__AS_DEFINE__' offsets.s | sed 's/#//g' | sed 's/__AS_DEFINE__/#define/g' > build/include/offsets.h
```

Which yields a file that looks like this and can be included in your assembly sources.

```
    #define MYSTRUCT_B  4
```

You can then use this directly.

```
#include "offsets.h"

    ldr r1, [r2, #MYSTRUCT_B]
```

Comment: See: [asm-offset.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/asm-offsets.c) and [Kbuild](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Kbuild) which implement this technique for ARM Linux.  Other architectures have the same type of files.  It generates output like, `->TI_TASK #12 offsetof(struct thread_info, task)`, which the `sed` transforms to `#define TI_TASK 12`.  The Linux assembler is pre-processed with `gcc -E` so all normal 'C' pre-processing concepts can be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
asm(
        "ldr r0, [r1, %[my_offset]] \n" : : [my_offset]"i" (offsetof(MyStruct, a))
    );
```